# Semantically, which is more correct: a in h2, or h2 in a?

Tags: html, standards, semantics

I'm stuck deciding which to use as both seem to work.

Should I be placing links `<a>` inside of `<h2>` elements?

Or the other way around?

What is the correct standard?

Comment: This is pretty subjective, but I'd say the `<a>` should be within the `<h2>` under the grounds that if part of the `<h2>`'s text wasn't a link, this is the way it'd have to be, but you'd rarely have the link span outside of the `<h2>`.

Comment: 3 votes to close. May I ask why? How is this not a real question? @AndrewMarshall: How is it subjective? I thought there were standards published?

Comment: Semantics are not standards. Since you *can* do either (in HTML5, at least), there's no technical reason to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can only place `<h2>` elements within `<a>` elements if you're working with HTML5, which [allows any other elements within `<a>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Previous specifications (or current ones however you want to look at them) never allowed this.

The usual way of doing this is to place `<a>` within `<h2>`. This works, has always worked, and has been the only valid way to do it before HTML5, for heading links, as the link refers to the text in that heading. You rarely need to place `<h2>` within `<a>` unless that `<h2>` is part of some more complex structure which functions as a hyperlink as a whole.

Comment: dude... forget about "valid" in the pedantic sense...it's all about display level.  If a is set to display:block it is fine, html4, xhtml1, html5...  Whatever.

Comment: @mikeyUX: Why are you telling me and not the OP this?

Answer (score 19):

Also its not functioning same, there is one big difference.

If you put `<h2>` into `<a>` the whole block (for example line) of heading will work like link.

However if you put `<a>` into `<h2>`, only visible text will work as link. (you can test it with cursor change)

Comment: What is meant by "Heading has higher importance"?

Comment: Sorry, when i just thought about it more it did not make any sense.

Comment: Voted your answer up because of the extra info, though it doesn’t really answer the question of which is semantically more correct.

Comment: This is easily solved by using CSS to give the inner A tag a display:block;
In that way the entire H2 will become filled by the internal A, and will entirely be clickable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that it depends...

From the W3C website, more specifically in the [HTML5 semantics page](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/semantics.html), it is clear that h2 elements (as all other heading tags) have as content model "Phrasing content".

Now, following the [Phrasing content link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/dom.html#phrasing-content-0), you get the following description:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing
>   content form paragraphs.

and in the following list you have that phrasing content include:

> a (if it contains only phrasing content)

**So, if the `a` tag includes only phrasing content, HTML5 allows it to be contained within a `h2` tag.**

Viceversa, the [text level semantics page](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) describes the `a` element content model as follows:

> Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Following the [Transparent link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/dom.html#transparent), at the end of the description is found the following:

> When a transparent element has no parent, then the part of its content
>   model that is "transparent" must instead be treated as accepting any
>   flow content.

Since in the [`h2` tag description](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/semantics.html) it is said:

> Contexts in which this element may be used:
>       Where flow content is expected.

an `h2` tag may the considered as flow content.

**So, if the `a` tag has no parent, in HTML5 it must be treated as accepting any flow content, including h2 tags.**

Comment: "So, if the a tag has no parent"
- No parent what? Element? Another heading tag?

Comment: The same reported in the Transparent Link quotation from the W3C website (http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/dom.html#transparent)... it is a parent element

Comment: Sorry, I should have connected it with your quote above.

Answer (score 3):

## HTML allows things inside `<a>` tags

I have this...

```
<header>
  <a href="/home">
    <h1>Main heading</h1>
    <h2>Sub heading</h2>
  </a>
</header>
```

And it works for me.

The whole heading text including the subheading is clickable as I want. I don't know of a better way to do this with html 5.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C [specs for h2](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h2.html) say that its permitted parent elements are anything that can contain flow elements, or hgroups.  The [specs for a](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a) permit parent elements that can contain phrasing *or* flow elements.  h2 can contain phrasing content, and a can contain phrasing or flow content, so based on the spec it appears that either is permitted.

Since you included the semantics tag, I assume you're interested in which 'seems' better too.  For my part, since I can't think of when I'd want an anchor to span a heading plus other content, but I can think of plenty of times when a header should contain an anchor plus other content, a inside h2 seems the best route to go.