# <a> inside <h2> or <h2> inside <a>?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Semantically, which is more correct: a in h2, or h2 in a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760074/semantically-which-is-more-correct-a-in-h2-or-h2-in-a)

I'm a little worried how this might affect SEO. Should `<a>` be placed inside an `<h2>` tag,

```
<h2><a href="#">Yey Me!</a></h2>
```

or vice versa?

```
<a href="#"><h2>Yey Me!</h2></a>
```

**DOCTYPE:** html5

Comment: Retagged the question to more properly reflect its body.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to get pedantic, personally, I'd say put the `<h2>` outside the `<a>` tag. It doesn't really matter though in my experience (which, admittedly, isn't that much).