# Header inside Link or Link inside Header in HTML markup?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is more correct: <h1><a>..</a></h1> OR <a><h1>..</h1></a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023512/which-is-more-correct-h1a-a-h1-or-ah1-h1-a)
>   [Semantically, which is more correct: a in h2, or h2 in a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760074/semantically-which-is-more-correct-a-in-h2-or-h2-in-a)

This is a simple question about HTML. What is the right/most preferable way to put a link in a header, paragraph or another HTML element?

This way:

`<h2><a href="">Some Title</a></h2>`

Or this way:

`<a href=""><h2>Some Title</h2></a>`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Better is

```
<h2><a href="">Some Title</a></h2>
```

because `h` is element with display block and is not good practice to have `block` in `a` element.

Answer (score 7):

To note: You can't put the header inside the link in HTML4.

In HTML5, it depends on the effect and semantic meaning you are going for. Putting the entire header inside the link will cause the clickable area to span the entire width, whereas putting the link inside the header will cause only the text to be clickable. I've used both versions before, but it completely depends on where I'm putting the header.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the second one :

```
<a href=""><h2>Some Title</h2></a>
```

because you have more control for example if you want to do something like this:

```
<a href=""><h2>Some Title</h2> <h1>biggest</h1></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

They both work just fine.

You can check for yourself at http://validator.w3.org/ if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, `<a>` is an inline-element, and `<h2>` is a block-level element, so:

```
<h2><a href="">Some Title</a></h2>
```

is the correct nesting.

That said, the browser will **generally** ignore incorrect nesting like that and allow you to do it the way you want to.

Me, I don't like tempting fate when it comes to a browser choosing to run my page in Standards-Compliance mode or Quirks mode so I'll choose the correct nesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1><a href="#">text here</a></h1>
```

is correct, as HTML does not allow a block element () within an inline element () (src). your second example will fail validation.

Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

I just copied this from another question ...