# Text pushing Div Down

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress Theme and im doing the post boxes on the main page. Currently, I've got a blurred background and then text overlaying that with a background on that to distinguish between the background and the text. For short titles, I am getting it to work, for longer titles the text is pushing down the actual photo box.

[image]

I've tried to get things to work but I'm not getting any progress or it just looks even weirder, some help with this would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="hanger">
<div class="h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php     the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>       </div>
<div id="bgdiv"><div id="hang-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>'); background-size: cover; height: 200px; -webkit-filter: blur(5px);-moz-filter: blur(5px); -o-filter: blur(5px); -ms-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px);   margin: -5px -10px -10px -5px; "></div>
</div></div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
#hanger {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#hanger h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#hanger a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#topbg {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #7f7f7f;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    top: -220px;
}

#bgdiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.h2 {
    background: url("./images/opac-grey.png");
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 698px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle or codepen demo? I guess the fixed height of `#topbg` is the cause of this, can you try changing that to `min-height:40px;` instead of `height:40px;`

Comment: @Aziz it's a wordpress site, so the JsFiddle doesnt transfer over the title etc. I'm not using `#topbg` anymore, so it's not that. Here's a link: http://theuntoldspiral.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the link, helped a lot! Your code is a bit complicated for a simple structure, all you need is a container div which has 3 things: title, background div, content div - it can be simplified as such:

> `post box > post background + post title + post content`
>
> which in code is the following:
>
> `.hanger > .hanger-bg + (h2>a) + .hanger-content`

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/qwmvh9og/)

HTML / WordPress Code

```
<!-- post box -->
<div class="hanger">
    <div class="hanger-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>');"></div>
    <!-- post title -->
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <!-- post content -->
    <div class="hanger-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end post -->

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS Code

```
/* post box */

.hanger {
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    position:relative;
}

/* post background */

.hanger-bg {
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    /* blur effect */
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

/* post title */

.hanger h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin:0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);*/
    background: url("./images/opac-grey.png");
    min-height:40px;
}

.hanger h2 a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* post content */

.hanger-content {
    padding:20px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

A Few notes:

- I placed the `a` link tag INSIDE the `h2` tag for [better semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760074/semantically-which-is-more-correct-a-in-h2-or-h2-in-a)
- The background div was achieved using the `position:absolute` + `z-index:-1;` css trick
- Please note that using the same `id` for more than one element is a syntax error - `id`s are unique so use classes instead. read more on [class vs id](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)