# How to add header H2 in PHP class

Tags: php, header

Im trying to obtain an H2 header for class "aawp-product__title"

```
<div class="aawp-product__content">
        <a class="aawp-product__title" href="<?php echo $this->get_product_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->get_product_link_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
            <?php echo $this->get_product_title(); ?>
        </a>
        <div class="aawp-product__description">
            <?php echo $this->get_product_description(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry, it's not clear (to me) what you are asking. There is no `"aawp-product__title"`, there is no `<h2>`

Comment: Do you understand your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what You actually want to achieve but this should be working good for You

```
<a class="aawp-product__title" href="<?php echo $this->get_product_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->get_product_link_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
        <h2><?php echo $this->get_product_title(); ?></h2>
    </a>
```

[Semantically, which is more correct: a in h2, or h2 in a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760074/semantically-which-is-more-correct-a-in-h2-or-h2-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, what I need is the aawp-product__title echo which returns a product title to be and H2 or H3 header.